# Overridden Extension Method Requires Assembly Reference

Tags: c#, .net, generics, .net-4.5, extension-methods

This seems strange unless I am missing something...

```
public static string ToDomainSolarSystemCelestial(this TypeMapper<string> m)
{
    // Does not reference any other assemblies - straight string to string mapping.
    return m.Source
}

public static Universe.SolarSystemCelestial ToDomainSolarSystemCelestial(this TypeMapper<Db.SolarSystemCelestial> m)
{
     // Maps between a database and business object. 
     // Requires a reference to the Db assembly.
     return new Universe.SolarSystemCelestial()
     {
         Id = m.Source.Id,
         // etc
     }
}
```

Both of these extension methods are defined in the same class. The second override needs to know what a Db.SolarSystemCelestial is so it needs a reference to the containing assembly. However the first is a straight string to string mapping.

Yet if I do this...

```
var x = Mapper.Map("x").ToDomainSolarSystemCelestial();
```

.. using the overload that has no dependencies, Visual Studio will complain with the following message:

`The type Db.SolarSystemCelestial is not defined in an assembly that is referenced. You must add a reference to assembly Db, Version 1.0.0.0...`

If I change the name of one of the methods the problem goes away. Is there a work around to this apart from changing the name? Ideally I would like the overrides to have the same name but deal with different types.

Thanks.

Note: There are questions about finding assemblies that are not referenced but in this case I am asking about the compilation of extension methods and not just a missing assembly reference.

Comment: The compiler needs to figure which overload to use, so it needs references to any types used in the signature of any of the overloads.

Comment: Changing the name of the methods would not fix this problem.  The error is about a missing reference.

Comment: Add references to referenced external assemblies you must, if code compile you want.

Comment: @Dbugger - I think this sounds right and makes sense.

Comment: @dbugger your comment should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Also, this question is definitely not a duplicate of the one marked. The other question does not talk about overloaded extension methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the base class of  Universe.SolarSystemCelestial?

Its something to do with the return type either being in a different assembly, or one of its base types, or types that it exposes publicly is in the other assembly.

EDIT:

After reading the question again with extra comments, the problem is as stated by @dbugger

One work around would be to have the extension methods in different namespaces, and in calling code only add the namespace you need. So compiler only sees one.

Comment: Universe.SolarSystemCelestial only has framework types in it.